# Oracle. How can I handle outer fields with IN operator and OUTER JOIN

Tags: oracle, join, outer-join

I wrote query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT 
          TABLE2.VAL AS VAL1,
          TABLE2.VAL AS VAL2,
          TABLE2.VAL AS VAL3,
          TABLE2.VAL AS VAL4,
          TABLE2.VAL AS VAL5,
          TABLE2.VAL AS VAL6,
          CASE 
             WHEN VAL1 IS NULL THEN '10'
             WHEN VAL3 IS NULL THEN '20'
             WHEN VAL5 IS NULL THEN '30'
             ELSE '40' 
          END PROGRESS
      FROM 
          TABLE1, TABLE2
      WHERE 
          TABLE1.KEY = TABLE2.KEY(+)
          TABLE2.COND IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6')
) 
WHERE 
    PROGRESS > '20'
```

This query is not working. There's an error in

```
,CASE WHEN VAL1 IS NULL THEN '10'
      WHEN VAL3 IS NULL THEN '20'
      WHEN VAL5 IS NULL THEN '30'
      ELSE '40' END PROGRESS
```

this part. error says VAL1 is incongruence.

I can resolve this if I use like this

```
FROM TABLE2 TB2_1, TABLE2 TB2_2, TABLE3 TB2_3
WHERE TB2_1.KEY(+) = TABLE1.KEY AND TB2_2.KEY(+) = TABLE1.KEY
```

declare same tables several times, but

I don't want to do this because the real query is much more complicated than this.

Is there any way that I can distinguish outer tables like this?

```
,CASE WHEN TABLE2[1].VAL IS NULL THEN '10'
      WHEN TABLE2[2].VAL IS NULL THEN '20'
      WHEN TABLE2[3].VAL IS NULL THEN '30'
      ELSE '40' END PROGRESS
```

Or any other way. help please :)

Comment: What is the meaning/intention of your `SELECT` statement?  You have aliased the same column 6 times.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE2
     ON TABLE1.KEY = TABLE2.KEY AND
        TABLE2.COND IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6')
```

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use aliases in your `CASE` statement:

```
CASE WHEN TABLE2.VAL IS NULL THEN '10'
     WHEN TABLE2.VAL IS NULL THEN '20'
     WHEN TABLE2.VAL IS NULL THEN '30'
    ELSE '40'
END PROGRESS
```

I don't know what the meaning of your `SELECT` statement is, since it has the same column aliased 6 times, but hopefully this answer will at least remove your current error.

You should also take the advice from @Gordon and use an explicit left (outer) join.  The syntax you are using is hard to read.